# How can I convert the json file taken with the api to a javascript object by parsing it with laravel?

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, api, parsing

I guess I need to use json.parse here but I don't know exactly how to use it.

Userscontroller.php

```
 function list(){


$clients = Clients::all();

$result["users"]=$clients;


return $result;
```

And data:

```
{
"users": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "fullName": "Deniz",
        "company": "Riskomer",
        "role": "editor",
        "username": "denden",
        "country": "Türkiye",
        "contact": "05355141450",
        "email": "hallobro82@gmail.com",
        "currentPlan": "Enterprise",
        "status": "inactive",
        "avatar": ""
    },
```

I need it turned out like this. In short, I need to convert the json object to javascript object as follows. How can I do this with Laravel?

```
users: [
{
  id: 1,
  fullName: 'Galen Slixby',
  company: 'Yotz PVT LTD',
  role: 'editor',
  username: 'gslixby0',
  country: 'El Salvador',
  contact: '(479) 232-9151',
  email: 'gslixby0@abc.net.au',
  currentPlan: 'enterprise',
  status: 'inactive',
  avatar: '',
},
```

Comment: Look into JSON.parse for your Javascript, also you should return a proper json response like

return response()->json($result->toJson(), 200);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to append a parameter to each resource, you should use `each()` and `setAttribute()` method.

```
$result = \App\Models\Clients::all()
    ->each(function (\App\Models\Clients $client) {
        return $client->setAttribute('testKey', 'testValue');
    });
```

And in your javascript code, just parse the javascript to convert the json to javascript object type.

```
JSON.parse('{!! $result !!}')
```

**Notice**: Be sure to echo `$result` with `{!! !!}` not with `{{ }}` to not escape special characters.

Comment: I use fetch api for getting data. Should I use there response.json() function?

Comment: Yes. You should use `response()->json($result);` in your laravel code.

Answer (score 0):

```
return Clients::all();
```

will Return Array Of Object

```
[{user1,user2,user3...}]
```

if you want to name this array just use it this way

```
$array=array('users'=>Clients::all());
return $array;
```

and the output will be like this

```
users:[{user1,user2,user3...}]
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.